# Method dispatch when mixing S3 and S4

Tags: r, r-s4, r-s3

I'd like to understand the steps R goes through to find the appropriate function when mixing S3 and S4. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(a=rep(c('a', 'b'), each=15),
                b=rep(c('x', 'y', 'z'), times=5),
                y=rnorm(30))

m <- lme4::lmer(y ~ b + (1|a), data=d)
l <- lsmeans::lsmeans(m, 'b')
multcomp::cld(l)
```

I don't fully understand what happens when the final line gets executed.

`multcomp::cld` prints `UseMethod("cld")`, so S3 method dispatch.

`isS4(l)` shows that `l` is an S4 class object.

It seems that, despite calling an S3 generic, the S3 dispatch system is completely ignored. Creating a function `print.lsmobj <- function(obj) print('S3')` (since `class(l)` is `lsmobj`) and running `cld(l)` does not print `"S3"`.

`showMethods(lsmobj)` or `showMethods(ref.grid)` (the super class), do not list anything that resembles a `cld` function.

Using `debugonce(multcomp::cld)` shows that the function that is called eventually is `cld.ref.grid` from `lsmeans`.

I was wondering, however, how to realise that `cld.ref.grid` will eventually be called without any "tricks" like `debugonce`. That is, what are the steps R performs to get to `cld.ref.grid`.

Comment: You really should upgrade lsmeans. You have a very old version. The lsmobj class went away a long time ago.

Comment: Ah I am aware of that. The question is not really linked to the package specifically, but to R's method dispatch system. It's just that I had to debug some code where lsmeans is still used, and used it therefore as example.

Comment: I wonder if you load the multcomp library first, if cld would show up in showMethods. That is, if the generic is not visible, why should methods be shown.

Comment: OP says '... cld(l) does not print "S3" ' but I think this is a typo, since you defined a `print` method, not a `cld` method.

Comment: @rvl, you're right. Wasn't thinking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for S3 methods to be registered, the generic has to be available. Here, I write a simple `foo` method for `merMod` objects:

```
> library(lme4)
> foo.merMod = function(object, ...) { "foo" }

> showMethods(class = "merMod")

Function ".DollarNames":
 <not an S4 generic function>

Function "complete":
 <not an S4 generic function>

Function "formals<-":
 <not an S4 generic function>

Function "functions":
 <not an S4 generic function>
Function: getL (package lme4)
x="merMod"

Function "prompt":
 <not an S4 generic function>
Function: show (package methods)
object="merMod"

> methods(class = "merMod")
 [1] anova          as.function    coef           confint        cooks.distance
 [6] deviance       df.residual    drop1          extractAIC     family        
[11] fitted         fixef          formula        getL           getME         
[16] hatvalues      influence      isGLMM         isLMM          isNLMM        
[21] isREML         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix   ngrps         
[26] nobs           plot           predict        print          profile       
[31] ranef          refit          refitML        rePCA          residuals     
[36] rstudent       show           sigma          simulate       summary       
[41] terms          update         VarCorr        vcov           weights
```

Neither list includes `foo`. But if we define the generic, then it shows up in `methods()` results:

```
> foo = function(object, ...) UseMethod("foo")
> methods(class = "merMod")
 [1] anova          as.function    coef           confint        cooks.distance
 [6] deviance       df.residual    drop1          extractAIC     family        
[11] fitted         fixef          foo            formula        getL          
[16] getME          hatvalues      influence      isGLMM         isLMM         
[21] isNLMM         isREML         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix  
[26] ngrps          nobs           plot           predict        print         
[31] profile        ranef          refit          refitML        rePCA         
[36] residuals      rstudent       show           sigma          simulate      
[41] summary        terms          update         VarCorr        vcov          
[46] weights
```

Now it includes `foo`

Similarly, in your example, `methods()` will reveal the existence of `cld` if you do `library(multcomp)`, because that is where the generic for `cld` sits.

Comment: This definitely helps, but I'd still like to know how R determines to call the function `cld.ref.grid` when executing `multcomp::cld(l)`.

Comment: Because `multcomp::cld` calls `UseMethod`, which in turn looks for possible methods for `l`, which is of class `c("lsmobj", "ref.grid")`; and finds there is indeed one registered for the `ref.grid` class but not one for `lsmobj`. So it uses the one for `ref.grid`. Method registration is done in the `NAMESPACE` file for **lsmeans**, which includes the line `S3method("cld", "ref.grid")`

Answer (score 1):

The older R documentation (pre-2016) used to contain more details than the current documentation but roughly speaking, the process is as follows in descending order of priority:

1) if the function is a standard S4 generic and any of the arguments in the signature are S4 (according to `isS4`), then the best S4 method is chosen according to the usual rules.

2) if the function is a nonstandard S4 generic then its body is executed, which at some point then calls S4 dispatch itself.

3) if the function is a S3 generic function then S3 dispatch takes place on the first argument (except for internal generic binary operators).

4) if the function isn't a generic at all, then it is evaluated in the usual way with lazy evaluation for all its arguments.

Note that from the help page from `setGeneric`:

"Functions that dispatch S3 methods by calling `UseMethod` are ordinary functions, not objects from the `"genericFunction"` class. They are made generic like any other function, but some special considerations apply to ensure that S4 and S3 method dispatch is consistent (see Methods_for_S3)."